# Search Engine Visibility Issue in WordPress

Tags: wordpress, google-search

There is an issue in the back-end that the Search Engine Visibility Checkbox is  disabled and I'm not able to check or uncheck the checkbox.

What is happening that when I load the page then it comes normal but at the end of loading it will appear like in below image.

I have uninstalled my all plugins and renamed the plugin directory too, but this issue still persist.

[image: a busy cat]
<sub>(source: [plego.us](http://email.plego.us/3dp/search-engine-visibility.jpg))</sub>

robots.txt Code.

```
User-agent: *
Crawl-delay: 1
Disallow: /wp-content/plugins/
Disallow: /wp-admin/
```

**Solution**

I just remane or remove mu-plugins directory in wp-content, my issue resolved.

Thanks

Comment: Check why it thinks this is your staging system. Probably a setting somewhere.

Comment: You Need To  manually looked at your robots.txt? http://yourdomainname.com/robots.txt and paste your robots.txt code here!

Comment: I have added robots.txt code

Comment: Side note but IMO, robots.txt file means nothing for bots that will want to look for something malicious. Also your site will have links to the plugins folder anyway

Comment: but i have removed the plugin folder ??

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure about your hosting environment (some hosting companies like WPEngine has their pre-activated plugin for the site).

However, if you really need to change the visibility option, you can try this,

- Go to yoursite.com`/wp-admin/options.php` (you will see all options of the site at once there)
- Find the option `blog_public` (better to use browser find option, ctrl+F and type `blog_public`
- Change its value 1 to 0 and save!

> sometimes if you have lots of options generated by the plugins you installed before and those options are not cleared, it might take long time to save, even might cross php max execution time limit. If that is the case, you need to change that value manually directly form database table `wp_options`, from the table, find `blog_public` and change its value.